# dbt macro for Databricks to flatten a column with arbitrarily nested JSON content

Tags: sql, json, databricks, dbt, databricks-sql

My goal is to write a dbt macro that will allow me to flatten a table column with arbitrarily nested JSON content.

I have already found a [wonderful tutorial](https://ayangt.notion.site/ayangt/Using-dbt-Macro-to-flatten-JSON-in-Snowflake-5bb56ab0b8704d4ea51f16904549acc5) for this for Snowflake, however I would like to implement this for Databricks (Delta Lake) - using SQL.

Ultimately, I am looking for the Databricks equivalent of the [LATERAL FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) function in Snowflake.

The following is an example of a source...

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uGfU.png)

If ultimately using SQL to transform to the following target state:

[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwMcA.png)

---

I have already looked at several projects, for example [json-denormalize](https://pypi.org/project/json-normalize/). However, I would like to implement this completely in SQL.

Also I have seen the Databricks functions `json_object_keys`, `lateral view`, `explode`, but can't make sense of how exactly I should ideally approach the problem.

Can someone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that most people here want sample table data and the expected result as properly formatted text (i.e. no images, no links.)

Comment: @jnmuehlenbrock did you ever resolve this? I'm thinking of using dbt and was wondering about the same problem and found your question

Comment: @EugeneNiemand Unfortunately not, I'm sorry.